# Is it possible to delete resume data after canceling the NSURLSession or Alamofire download request?

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsurlsession

When I cancel the NSURLSession or Alamofire download request and close the app, I found there is still big data in my app.
I think it may be resume data. I don't want to resume the download.
I wanna delete the resume data after canceling the download request.
How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried resuming it and then canceling it without requesting resume data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLSession cancelByProducingResumeData does not produce resume data.

Answer (score 1):

I *think*, but am not certain, that you can cause the on-disk content to be thrown away as follows:

- Resume the request with the previously obtained resume data
- Immediately cancel it by calling `cancel` (not `cancelByProducingResumeData:`)

Alternatively, I think that the space is reclaimed automatically if the server returns a 404 error when you try to resume the download, but don't quote me on that.

Either way, the NSURLSession machinery should eventually reap those temporary files without intervention, so unless you think it's a significant problem (e.g. if your app routinely downloads multi-gigabyte files and then abandons the downloads), you can probably just ignore the extra disk space.